How to Change Screen Display Settings When Primary Screen Has Failed
This evening, my secondary laptop (not the one I'm typing this question on) suddenly developed a case of chronic black screening. The first time, it black screened after being on for a few hours. Tried pressing the power button, and pressing again to turn it back on, because there was not much else I could do. Unfortunately, the problem seems to be getting worse and worse; as I've hard restarted several times, the time from power on until black screen has shrunk from minutes to tens of seconds to seconds...
I have a workaround that I'm almost sure would work. I have an external monitor. If I could just switch the display setting from treating the external monitor as a screen 2 to treating the laptop monitor and the external monitor as the same screen, I could just use the external monitor and ignore (for now) the fact that the laptop screen has gone black. I'm almost certain this would work because during the first few hard resets, when I still had minutes before the black screen happened and I had time to log into Windows, the external monitor displayed my Windows desktop background, and continued doing so even after the laptop screen went black.
Unfortunately, in the current display setting, opening the display settings causes a window to open in screen 1, i.e. the screen that has gone black. (I came really close to actually implementing this fix once; but unfortunately the black screen hit before the settings window could load in screen 1). So I'm stuck in a catch 22: I can't work around the black screen because I can't change the display setting; but I can't change the display setting because trying to do so opens the window in the screen that has gone black.
Any way to break out of this?
Thanks

It's probably just a problem with the backlight. Much cheaper than replacing the whole screen. Meanwhile use Windows+P to toggle monitor modes. Use the key combo as many times as needed to either get to the mirrored screen (instead of the extended) or just the external monitor. Yes, it's the same combo that we use to manage projectors.

@ChanganAuto, Win+P might be made an answer that would be helpful to others, too.

Hi, turns out just keeping the computer after a forced hard shut down was enough to delay the black screen after the next boot long enough to change said display setting. So this will do for the time being. But now the hard part: How to fix the black screen. I doubt it's just because the computer screen is broken; I replaced the screen not too long ago. It's probably a connection problem between the brains and the screen. Well, thanks
